# How to write css selector for selecting element before a given element

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector, siblings, combinators

I have two elements inside a wrapper div. The second sibling in the view sometimes get an active class (as per the logic of UI)

```
   <div id="wrapper">
     <div>some content</div>
     <div class="active">some other content</div>
   </div>
```

In those cases (when second child has an active class) - How can I target the 1st div from a css selector.

I've tried general sibling of the active div

```
.active ~ div
```

But this doesn't work since the target div should follow the selected div and should not be before it.

How to target a div which comes **before** another active div.

Comment: You can't. However, you can select things that are *not* `.active`, and also make use of `:first-child()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the div which is not active (inside wrapper class)

```
.wrapper {
  > div:not([class='active']) {
    // apply styles 
  }
}
```

Comment: there maybe a case - when the first div is active and second is not active - then this would mean the second div. 
but i want the scenario only when the second is active - and in that scenario - the 1st div

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. The above CSS will be applied to the div which is NOT active, regardless it is first or second. Does it make sense? I can provide a fiddle or codepen if you like

Comment: only when the second is active - i want to select the 1st.
If the 1st is active - i dont want that selector to select the 2nd